# Values are'nt saved in onSaveInstanceState while leaving the activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-navigation

I am trying to save values while leaving from activity and retrieve when coming back to screen.
So I'm using onSaveInstanceState method to save data and using Bundle object from onCreate method while coming back.

Below is my scenario..

Activity A:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Object received from savedInstanceState");
    }
    else{
    Log.d(TAG, "savedInstanceState value is null");
    }
}

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "In onSaveInstanceState");
    savedInstanceState.putString("obj_name", DashBoardDisplay_l.getName());
    }

OnClickListener save_click = new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PointLogActivity.class);
i.putExtra("ref_name", Name_ref);
startActivity(i);}};
```

I could see the log for onSaveInstanceState method while leaving to PointLogActivity.

PointLogActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
Intent intent = getIntent();
String YourtransferredData = intent.getExtras().getString("ref_name");
Log.d(TAG, "ref name "+YourtransferredData);
Name=YourtransferredData;
//For getting back button
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

I am coming back to Activity A by click back button in top left of the activity. 
But while coming back to Activity, I could not find date from Bundle object and getting log from null condition.

```
savedInstanceState value is null
```

So can someone tell where I am going wrong.

Comment: You should override onSavedInstanceState. The value of savedInstanceState will be null if its a new instance of the activity, so check your activity life cycle and make sure that you are storing your state in the correct place. I recommend onPause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by putting the below at parent activity in manifest file.

android:launchMode="singleTop">